# Finding an orthonormal basis of the space of all functions in P2 that are orthogonal to $f(t) = t$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Consider the space P2 with inner product 
>   $$ 
> \frac 12 \int_{-1}^1 f(t)g(t)\,dt
>  $$
>   Find an orthonormal basis of the space of all functions in P2 that are orthogonal to $f(t) = t$.

I'm trying to figure out the basis for W. If we solve $\int_{-1}^1 t(at^2 + bt + c)dt = 0 $ we get:
$$\frac a4 + \frac b3 + \frac c2 - (\frac a4 - \frac b3 + \frac c2) = 0 $$
This gives us 
$$ \frac {2b}3 = 0$$
So W includes all the functions in P2 where b = 0. I'm still struggling to get to the last step, find an orthonormal basis. W -> (1, 0, 1) * (a, b, c).

EDIT: This gives us a basis of 1 and x^2. Doing grahm schmidt we get:

$$v1 = 1 $$

$$ v2 = x^2 - \frac {<x^2, 1>}{<1, 1>} * 1$$

Integrating for $<x^2, 1>$ we get $\frac 23$ this gives us $x^2 - \frac 23$

So our orthonormal basis is: 
$ 1 $ and $ x^2 - \frac 23$

Comment: $-1/2t\not\equiv 0$ is a multiple of $t$, they can't be orthogonal.

Comment: thank you for that! What would then be orthogonal to f(t) = t ?

Comment: what is the integral of $t$?

Comment: Hint: You should solve $\int^1_{-1} t (at^2 + bt + c) = 0$ in general ...

Comment: @user251257 how did you know to solve for that integral, specifically how did you know it was $t(at^2 + bt + c)$, how did you know to multiply by t?

Comment: You take an arbitrary element of $P2$ (assuming it means a polynomial of degree $\le2$). You are basically done. You have shown, $at^2 + bt + c$ is orthogonal to $t$ iff $b=0$.

Comment: But this isn't an orthonormal basis yet -- do I have to find a basis of W and then do grahm schmidt?

Comment: @Maddie Yup.$\ $

Comment: @Maddie Guess or gram Schmidt. Some simple guess in your mind?

Comment: @user251257, I'm quite stumped. I'm still lost as to what the basis would be of W.

Comment: @user251257 if we know b = 0 is the answer to the integral, then we just have to make (1, 0, 1) a unit vector ?

Comment: @Maddie it is a space of polynomials, so the basis should contain polynomials. What about $1$ and $t^2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already had
$$
W=\{at^2+bt+c\mid b=0,a,c\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{a\cdot t^2+c\cdot 1\mid a,c\in\mathbb{R}\}\tag{1}
$$
Note that $W$ is a vector space. Here are the [simpler related questions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It) you should try

- Do you know what it means by *a* basis for $W$?
- By looking at (1), can you identify a basis for $W$?
- Once you have a basis of $W$, do you know how to turn it to an orthonormal one?

---

There seems to be confusion about a vector in $P_2$ and its *coordinate* with respect to some basis. I assume here that $P_2$ means the set of real polynomials with degree at most $2$. Considers the basis $\{1,t,t^2\}$ for $P_2$, then $(1,0,1)$ is the coordinate of the vector $1+t^2$. It is *not* an element of $P_2$, but the vector $1+t^2$ is.

Answer (score 0):

$P2$ is not a sufficiently "standard" notation to use without explanation.  I would suspect that the polynomials of degree $\le 2$ are meant here, but you should go to your instructor (or the source of the problem) to clarify this.

Assuming the polynomials of degree $\le 2$ are meant, you should calculate

$$ \int_{-1}^1 t (a_0 + a_1 t + a_2 t^2)\; dt$$
to see what is the condition on the coefficients $a_0$, $a_1$ and $a_2$ needed for such a polynomial to be orthogonal to $t$.

Comment: solving for that integral = 0, I got down to b = 0. Does this mean W includes all functions $x^2 + c $?

Comment: @Maddie It's all polynomials of the form $\color{red}ax^2+c$ (this is a $2$-dimensional space and thus should have $2$ parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You are integrating with limits $-1$ and $+1$; if the function is an odd function this would result in zero. Which polynomials $g(t)$ of degree at most 2, would make $tg(t)$ an odd function?

Those with $tg(t)$ having no $t^2$ term would fit the bill. This translates to  $g(t)$ be of the form $a+bt^2$,; so the two functions $g_0(t)\equiv1$ and $g_1(t)=t^2$ which are linearly independent  form a basis (as this has to be a proper subspace of $P_2$, a 3-dimensional vector space, they should be all). But their inner product is not zero. So they do not form an orthogonal  basis.  But now you can try out integrating $a+bt^2$ and find the answer.